# C++ unable to set NULL pointer to static variable containing object?

Tags: c++, static, null

Apologies ahead of time, as I am not even sure how to phrase the question, but I was working on a homework assignment (to which the question is unrelated except that I ran into the problem working on the assignment) and came across certain problem (this is just an extraction and generalization, I left out destructors, etc...):

```
class idType {
    int _id;
  public:
    int getID() { return _id; }
    idType(int in = -1) : _id(-1) {}
};


class Foo {
    static int _count;
    idType* _id; //int wrapper just for examples sake
  public:
    Foo() { _id = new idType(_count); ++_count; }
    idType* getID() { if(_id) return _id; return NULL; } //ERROR WHEN CALLED FROM BELOW
};

class Bar {
    Foo* _foo;
  public:
    Bar(Foo* foo = NULL) : _foo(foo) {}
    Foo* getFoo() { if(_foo) return _foo; return NULL; }
};

int foo::_count = 0;

int main() {
    Bar BAR;
    if(BAR.getFoo()->getID() && BAR.getFoo()); //RUN TIME ACCESS VIOLATION ERROR
    return 0;
};
```

As I mentioned, this is not the code I am working with, but I believe it more clearly identifies what is happening.  BAR passes the getFoo() check, so _foo isn't(?) NULL but getFoo()->getID() faults at if(_id).

Is the static variable somehow preventing any NULL instance of a pointer to that class type from existing?
The reason I asked that at first was because when I commented out the static variable lines in my original program, the program worked fine.  HOWEVER, after trying this code (which more or less emulates what I am doing) removing the static variable lines makes no difference, it still faults the same.

This may be simple, but I am at a loss as to what is wrong.  Thank you much for any help.

Comment: Look up short circuiting. You have your conditions switched.

Comment: This is kind of silly: `BAR.getFoo()->getID() && BAR.getFoo()`.  You will have already used `BAR.getFoo()` to invoke `getID()` before you attempt to test `BAR.getFoo()` for null.

Comment: (PS: You should learn to format your code properly.  Throwing everything on one line leads to errors.)

Comment: `if (_id) return _id; return NULL;` and `if (_foo) return _foo; return NULL;` => *If X is not null then return X else if X is null then return null*. Isn't it a little redundant? Just return X immediately and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you all, as pointed out I had the && operands backwards, I don't know why but for some reason I thought that && evaluated the right hand side first and then the left only if the right 'passed'.

Answer (score 1):

Check pointers before using them.

```
int main() 
{
  Bar BAR;
  Foo *pFoo = BAR.getFoo();
  if (pFoo && pFoo->getID())
  {
    // do something
  }
  return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a `Foo` instance anywhere, and not passing a `Foo*` to the `Bar` constructor, so `Bar::_foo` gets initialize to NULL, which is what `Bar::getFoo()` returns.  And then your `if` statement crashes due to your backwards use of short-circuit logic (you are trying to access `Foo::getID()` before first validating that `Bar::getFoo()` returns a non-NULL `Foo*` pointer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass pointer to Foo object to BAR

```
int main() {
    Bar BAR(new Foo);
     //Reverse the condition, check for pointer validity first
    if(BAR.getFoo() && BAR.getFoo()->getID());
    return 0;
};
```

Provide the destructor to cleanup _foo  after usage

```
~Bar() {  if(_foo) delete _foo; _foo=NULL; }
```